# To check if a set is bounded in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The question is to check if the set $(0,\infty)$ is a bounded set in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},\rho) $

where $(\mathbb{R},\rho) = \min\{1,|x-y|\}$

I am getting confused half way through the logic. I am proceeding as follows:-

$(0,\infty)$ is a bounded set in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ if it is contained in a ball of finite radius that is

there exists  $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and, a $r>0$ such that for all $s \in (0,\infty)$ with $d(x,s) < r$, that is $\min \{1,|x-s|\} < r$.  How do I proceed from here? for eg if I take $s$ as $5$?
Request help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You could use the Archimedean Principle

Comment: Hint: What is the ball centered at $s = 5$ with radius $r=2$?

Comment: Could you pl give additional hint on use of Archimedean principle?